# how can fetch value from database

Tags: laravel-4

when we can type a letter in textbox.. onkeyup action done. go to search database and than display the corrosponding words below..
eg: i enter A,then display Apple,Ant(my database table contain this words staring letter is A) how can fetch value from database .
my controller.php is

```
public function executeSearch()
{$keywords=Input::get('keywords');
    $users=User::all();
    $searchUsers=new\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
    foreach($users as $u)
    {
    if(Str::contains(Str::Lower($u->name),Str::Lower($keywords)))
        $searchUsers->add($u);
    }
    return View::make('searchUsers')
    ->with('searchUsers',$searchUsers);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use SQL's `LIKE`:

```
$users = User::query();

foreach($keywords as $keyword){
    $users->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
}

$users = $users->get();
```

Then pass it to your view:

```
return View::make('searchUsers')->with('users', $users);
```

And loop over the results in the view:

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    Name: {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: how to display value in webpage?

Comment: Well exactly like you're currently doing it. Just pass `$users` to the view

Comment: my search blade.php is ......<form method="Post" role="form">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" id="search-input" class="form-control"
 placeholder="search" onkeydown="down()" onkeyup="up()">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12" id="search-result">
</div>
</div>
</form>
<script src="'js/search.js"></script>

Comment: my search .js  is........var timer;
function up()
{
 timer=setTimeout(function()
 {
  var keywords=$('#search-input').val();
  if(keywords.length>0)
  {
   $.post('http://localhost/search/lara/public/executeSearch',{keywords:keywords},function(markup)
   {
    $('#search-result').html(markup);
   });
  }
 },
 500);
}
function down()
{
 clearTimeout(timer);
}

Comment: What do you mean you can't write that?

Comment: srry its not work...have an error..... Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: That's a routing problem. Use `$.get()` or change your route to accept POST requests.

Comment: my searchUsers.blade.php...@foreach($users as $user)
    Name: {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach

Comment: my routes..Route::get('/',function()
{
 return View::make('search');

});
Route::post('executeSearch',array('uses'=>'SearchController@executeSearch'));

Comment: Look, you asked for a way to search by keywords. I was assuming you had the rest of your application (the actual request for search) working already. Instead of just posting me all your code and errors, first try to figure out what's wrong on your own please.

Comment: my routes.php page is...Route::get('/',function()
{
 return View::make('search');

});
Route::post('executeSearch',array('uses'=>'SearchController@executeSearch')); my controller.php is..........public function executeSearch()
    {
     $keywords=Input::get('keywords');
     $users=User::all();
     //$searchUsers=new\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
     foreach($keywords as $keyword){
          $users->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
             }

         $users = $users->get();
     return View::make('searchUsers')
        ->with('users', $users);
    }

Comment: my search.blade.php is..........
 


 <form method="Post" role="form">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" id="search-input" class="form-control"
 placeholder="search" onkeydown="down()" onkeyup="up()">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12" id="search-result">
</div>
</div>
</form>
<script src="'js/search.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: my search.js is.....var timer;
function up()
{
 timer=setTimeout(function()
 {
  var keywords=$('#search-input').val();
  if(keywords.length>0)
  {
   $.post('http://localhost/search/lara/public//',{keywords:keywords},function(markup)
   {
    $('#search-result').html(markup);
   });
  }
 },
 500);
}
function down()
{
 clearTimeout(timer);
}my searchUsers.blade.php......@foreach($users as $user)
    Name: {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach

Comment: when we can type a letter in textbox.. onkeyup action done. go to database table then check that letter is there(if enter B check B letter  is here .then display that all words below the textbox) . eg: i enter A,then display Apple,Ant(my database table contain this words staring letter is A)

Comment: Is it possible that you hit enter and the form gets submitted? Or do you see the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` in your browser console?